# Do consequences grant you Fate points when compelled by opponents?

Tags: fate, dresden-files, compels

I've run a quick search though the site and I didn't seem to find this topic covered, so I'm asking:

In Dresden Files RPG when an opponent compels one of your consequences against you (spending a FATE point, not using a free tag) do you get the spent point for yourself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer the question, let's connect the dots in the rulebook.

On `YS203` the following quote is found:

> Stress is a transitory thing, but sometimes conflicts will have
>   lasting effects on a character— serious injuries, embarrassments,
>   phobias, and the like. These effects are collectively called
>   consequences, and they are a special kind of **aspect**.

The emphasis on aspect is mine- put in to show that a consequence is an aspect.  This is not the only place that a consequence is referred to as an aspect, either, so it is intentional, i.e. on `YS204` the following quote is found:

> Also keep in mind that, because a consequence is an aspect, it can be
>   tagged, invoked, and compelled like any other aspect. Opponents with
>   fate points will take advantage of this, because invoking a
>   consequence to help win a fight is very easy to justify. Further, the
>   attacker that inflicted the consequence gets one tag on it (which he
>   may give to an ally), just like aspects placed by a maneuver.

With that in mind, we go back to the standard rules for compelling an aspect, i.e. on `YS98`:

> Compel: Either receive a fate point when one of your character’s
>   aspects works to his disadvantage, or spend a fate point to avoid that
>   disadvantage.

One other thing to note with Consequences as Aspects: **All** the rules for aspects apply, so if appropriate, you can invoke one of your **own** consequences for a positive effect, something which people sometimes miss.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for mentioning that you can invoke your own consequences.

Comment: I just want to reiterate something touched on compels don't always need to be negative either, I have compelled players to keep another from doing something monumentally stupid when the aspects were there to do so

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer to  your question is both yes and no.

YS100 states,

> "When you are the target of a compel, ... you have a choice: spend a fate point and ignore the aspect, or accept the complications and limitations on your character’s choices and receive a fate point.
>
> When you accept the fate point, the aspect is officially compelled."

However, YS106 talks about tagging:

> "Tags, even if they are to a character’s detriment, do not award a fate point like a normal invocation would."

Comment: Careful, you are comparing tags to compels, which are different ways to use aspects. Tags are the free version of invokes, not compels. Even if you just placed an aspect on an opponent with a maneuver, you have to pay a fate point to compel it.

Comment: @edgerunner sorry but you wrong. As stated here (http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/FateRPG/message/19519) by Fred Hicks and here by _someoneelse_ (http://evilhat.wikidot.com/fate-v3:aspects) free tag can initiate invoke for effect which can then initiate compel versus aspect owner. So basically this mean free compel on newly placed aspect via free tag.

Comment: In the case mentioned, it would be the GM doing the compelling, not you, and you cannot receive the fate point if the compelled player rejects the compel. So I'm still right that **you** cannot compel for free. You can only **cause** a compel for free, not make one.

Comment: @edgerunner In raw Dresden Files version of fate compels is always between GM and compelled side. So as player you never will receive fate point from rejected compel you initiated. It is in Diaspora compel can originated from players also. But even in Diaspora rejected compell do not give fatepoints. So yes, you right and you also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to note you get fate points **even** if someone free **tag** your aspect/consequence.
In Fate Points Economy Flow free tag is still invoke/compel vs owner of aspect/consequence but FP cost is credited by GM instead.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Flenyar Fred Hicks post on Yahoo groups - (http://games.groups.yahoo.com/group/FateRPG/message/19519) also there was post on http://www.jimbutcheronline.com about this exact situation with exact this Hicks answer, but i cant find it right now

Comment: and this http://evilhat.wikidot.com/fate-v3:aspects 
Tagging Another Character's Aspect 'For Effect' - This is basically paying the GM to force a specific compel on the target.